# How do you calculate the percent of rows in a table that are in each of the four quartiles in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do you calculate the percent of rows in a table that are in each of the four quartiles? For example, in a table that just has a list of scores, how can I get a result so that I get for instance 20% are in Q1, 20% in Q2, 30% in Q3, and 30% in Q4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirstQuartileCount :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Table1 ),
    FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Score] <= PERCENTILE.INC ( Table1[Score], 0.25 ) )
)
```

Duplicate, amending the 0.25 to 0.5 (second quartile), 0.75 (third quartile) and 1 (fourth quartile).